# How to get specific program on windows search

Tags: windows, search

I'm trying to set windows search to return some specific results on keywords search.

For example, I would like to find the word `markdown` and get the program **Typora** as the result.

Same way, I would like to search for `cmd` and to get a **cmder** as result.

So my concern is how to configure the windows search feature to give me specific results or programs to specific keyword searches.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only one way : Rename the program to include the keyword in the name.

Windows search is a simple tool that is not made for such usage.

Comment: Thanks! This will do the trick for the moment.